# Custom increment id

Tags: php

In a table I have a field, it is not an auto increment, with each new record it should increase by one, but having padding starting with 1, then 0

```
function getCustomId() {

// connect and select query


    $CustomID = "";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $CustomID = substr($row['CustomID'], 0, -4);
    }

    $CustomID = sprintf("%08d", ++$CustomID); 
    $CustomID .= "-DIST"

    return $CustomID;
```

The above function returns and insert for each new row the following

```
00000001-DIST
00000002-DIST
00000003-DIST
```

and so on

But I need a result starting with 1. And then incrementing.
For Example:

```
10000001-DIST
10000002-DIST
10000003-DIST
.....
12000023-DIST
```

Comment: How about: `$CustomID = "1" . sprintf("%07d", ++$CustomID) . "-DIST";`? You must have a very good reason to do this, which you didn't tell us, in all other cases simply use a normal auto increment. You might want to consider putting this in a transaction, to prevent duplicate and missing numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion didn't work. After insert record, only first row is correct. Here's what happens - 10000001-DIST, 110000002-DIST, 1110000003-DIST. The numbers must be eight and start with 1, not 11..., 111...

Comment: That's because sprintf with a format specifier `%07d` will get you a value _longer_ than 7 characters, if the input number is already more than 7 digits long.